# How do I audit which users are marked as "force.com Flow User"s?

Tags: soql, visual-workflow, user-admin

When using flows, there is a checkbox on the user details to enable that user as a "force.com Flow User."

I have tried to create a user view that shows this field, but I can't see it as an option for a display column.  Additionally, I tried to build a SOQL query, but I can't seen an attribute on the User table for Flow Users.

Without looking individually at each user's details, how do I identify all the users that are marked and all the ones that aren't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field is called UserPermissionsInteractionUser so your query to get all the Flow enabled users should be:

```
SELECT Id,Username FROM User WHERE UserPermissionsInteractionUser=TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks PepeFloyd.  Looking back I see I could have just gone through all the attributes that I didn't recognize, check their labels, and I would have found this out on my own.  Was it experience, brute force, or cheatsheet that you turned to, to map the label to the field name?

Comment: Experience, I was an SME for this product at Salesforce support a few years ago.